# How to use semantic-ui rail element

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am trying to create a vertical left menu using semantic-ui. Something like admin menu. To make it aligned into left, I tried to use rail element provided by semantic-ui. But my content is not visible.

I tried with example code provided in the site. But result is still the same. what am I missing here?

```
<body>
  <div class="ui segment">
    <div class="ui left dividing rail">
        <div class="ui segment">
            Left Rail Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui right dividing rail">
        <div class="ui segment">
            Right Rail Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I saw semantic-ui documentation site also using similar approach for showing their right menu. If this is not a best approach to create admin menu, please suggest any other better way using semantic ui.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify size and position of an central element. For example:

```
<body>
  <div class="ui segment" style="left:400px;width:600px;">
    <div class="ui left dividing rail">
        <div class="ui segment">
            Left Rail Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui right dividing rail">
        <div class="ui segment">
            Right Rail Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put them in a `grid` container, then add a `four wide column` before main `segment`. 
You should also set the main `segment` `eight wide column` to make it at the center (p.s. 16 = 4 + 8 + 4).

Run the code snippet in full page please.

```html
<script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="ui grid container">
  <div class="ui four wide column">

  </div>
  <div class="ui segment eight wide column">
    <div class="ui left rail">
      <div class="ui segment">
        Left Rail Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui right rail">
      <div class="ui segment">
        Right Rail Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>main content here..................................................</p>
    <p>main content here..................................................</p>
    <p>main content here..................................................</p>
    <p>main content here..................................................</p>
    <p></p>
  </div>

  <div class="ui four wide column">

  </div>
</div>
```